# Linux Syscall write: Does the kernel guarantee data write sequence?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I know that the kernel guarantees, if not intterupted, a certain size (it's saied to be PIPE_BUF, 4096Bytes) of data been write atomically, which means other process who's trying to read blocks.

Yet I've been wondering that, if I write morea block of data (say "abc...[x bytes]...xyz") to a storage device, during the time the kernel performs the action, will the kernel write abc first, and xyz last?

If not, then some other process may happen to read "***...[x bytes]...xyz" before the write action completes. That is certainly a disaster to many application, I think.

Does someone know the implemention, or, where can I find the answer in the kernel source?

Look forward to your replies! Thanks!

[update 2011.11.12]

I looked into the source code, but I can't comprehend it fully. I found out the calling chain "write -> vfs_write -> do_sync_write [loops] -> generic_file_aio_write [inode_mutex] -> __generic_file_aio_write -> .. -> generic_perform_write -> .. -> __copy_from_user(to, from, n)

__copy_from_user is an macro/function implemented with architecture dependent asm codes, and I'm not able to comprehend them now. But I think the coder will do it as most of us thinks what it should be...

Hopes for furthur clarification~

Comment: Take a look at "Eat My Data" as a starting point: http://flamingspork.com/talks/

Comment: Thanks. I read the presentation. It's practical and described many problems, but it's not deep enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

The data might not be physically flushed to disk in the order you wrote it, so if the machine crashes in the middle of writing, you *might* see "xyz" without "abc" after the system boots back up.  But assuming the machine stays running, the kernel will ensure that all writes appear to happen in the correct order.

Comment: Yeah, I fully comprehend the kernel's implemention of caching; but I need some proof to confirm the write sequence... Should I look into the source code?

Answer (score 2):

The correct order is always obeyed.

But in a non-atomic write to a sink which has several writers, it can happen that the received data contains, say, `"abc...[n bytes]...[data from other writer]...[m bytes]...xyz"`, where `n+m=x`.

So the data gets inserted a completely different data block.

On an atomic write, such things don't happen.

EDIT: To be clear, this is about pipes and FIFOs only. What about files, I don't know.

Comment: so... In what condition will the kernel treat a write as atomic?

Comment: as you said in your question - if the write size is below `PIPE_BUF`: [Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/write.html)

Comment: Thank. I read the man page, which relates PIPE_BUF to only pipes/FIFO ("with the following exceptions", it says). I wonder whether there's some similar constant with regular files...

Comment: Oomph, you are right. I haven't found anything about files in this way. But I suppose that even here the write order is obeyed as well. What about atomicity, I don't know.

Comment: I looked into the source, write calls vfs_write, which calls do_sync_write, which finally calls __copy_from_user(to, from, n), which is architecture dependent macro/function with assemblies... I'm not able to comprehend those asm codes currently, but I think the coder will do as most thinks...

Answer (score 0):

lets say i'm writing abc, which is 4k, and def, which is 4k.

The kernel won't guarantee that if I write "abcdef" in an 8k chunk, that another process won't see "abc", and then see "def" as two separate writes.

But if I just write 4k of "abc" the kernel guarantees that any other process will never see "a" then "b" then "c"

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_14.html#SEC215

You're on a different track.  The guarantee that you want is that "xyz" will never be read before "abc".  This is a different guarantee completely.  In fact, it's more than a guarantee.  It just goes without saying.  And it has nothing to do with flushing blocks to disk.  That's a different level of the system.